# Set border-radius of jspDrag?

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

I'm using jScrollPane with an image for the jspDrag class.  I have everything working properly, but I would like the top and bottom of the drag portion of the scrollbar to be rounded.  I have rounded the image, but it does not show up.

This is my css for the jspDrag class:

```
.jspDrag
{
    background-image:url(../images/Scrollbar/scrollbar_innerbar.png) !important;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have tried adding border-radius, but that does not work.